# AWS Lambda: python packages not found after deploy

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

###### What I do

I have a the standard hello_world sample code from aws, created via `sam init --runtime <runtime> --name <project-name>`.

I add `pytest` to requirements.txt and add `import pytest` to `app.py`.

I build and deploy via `sam build --template-file template.yaml && sam deploy  --template-file template.yaml --config-env dev --profile awsprofile`

###### Problem

When I run the function on AWS it fails at importing `pytest`, claiming no such package is there.

What could be the problem?

###### Notes

- The local `.aws-sam/build` folder contains the pytest package, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

###### Problem:

You deploy via `sam deploy --template-file ...`. When you do that the packages from the requirements.txt file will not be deployed.

###### Solution:

Don't state the template for deploy.

```
sam build --template-file template.yaml && sam deploy --config-env dev --profile awsprofile
```

###### Side note

Regarding the build step: In case you use samconfig.toml files, know that you can state the template file there as well as `template = "template.yaml"`